# is it possible to comment using github for mac?

Tags: github, github-for-mac

I very much like the ability to comment on commit diffs which are viewable on github. Is there any way I can do this using github for mac?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If you select a repository, chose 'Changes' from the menu and write your comment in "Commit summary" with additional information in the "Extended description" field.

When you commit, the "Commit summary" is your 'comment'.

Comment: Suppose I do a pull and have someone elses commits pulled down -- can I comment on those commits?

Comment: I'm afraid I cant answer that. But here's a qualified guess: Since you only comment your own commits, I'd say no. Also I'm not sure if Github for Mac supports pull requests, as far as I know it 'only' supports commits, add and push functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you can't directly comment on individual lines of code from the Mac GUI. However, if you click on the little picture of a gear and choose "View on Github" you'll be taken to the Github website for the remote master where you can comment on any line of code.